# keyup sometimes firing twice

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Why `keyup` sometimes firing twice?

I followed to use unbind and bind but seems not working.

**My code [HTML]:**

```
   <div id="otpmsg" class="error-otp text-center"></div>
    <div id="otp" name="otp" class="form-group text-center">
     <input class="m-2 text-center otp-control otp-control-solid" type="text" id="first" maxlength="1" />
     <input class="m-2 text-center otp-control otp-control-solid" type="text" id="second" maxlength="1" />
     <input class="m-2 text-center otp-control otp-control-solid" type="text" id="third" maxlength="1" />
     <input class="m-2 text-center otp-control otp-control-solid" type="text" id="fourth" maxlength="1" />         
    </div>
```

**Javascript part:**

```
    $('#otp').unbind('keyup');
      $('#otp').bind('keyup', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        const inputs = document.querySelectorAll('#otp > *[id]');
        let compiledOtp = '';
            for (let i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
                compiledOtp += inputs[i].value;
            }
        otp = compiledOtp;
          if(otp.length == 4) {
          ....
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`keyup` event is triggered when a key is released. When a key combination is used (e.g. `Shift + Tab`) the event will be triggered two or more times depending on the key combination used.

The `keyup` event will be triggered twice for the key combination `Shift + Tab`. One event for the `Shift` and one event for the `Tab`.

You can handle this case by writing a condition in the callback function to allow only numbers (considering the OTP will be numeric) by taking the value of the key pressed by the user using the `event.key` property.

```
$("#otp").on("keyup", function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  const pressedKey = e.key;
  if (!/^[0-9]+$/.test(pressedKey)) {
    return;
  }

  const inputs = document.querySelectorAll("#otp > *[id]");
  let compiledOtp = "";
  for (let i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
    compiledOtp += inputs[i].value;
  }
  otp = compiledOtp;
  if (otp.length == 4) {
  ...
});
```

For more information, please refer to the documentation https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/key

Comment: I tried without shit/alt + tab, it still firing twice sometimes

Comment: I think it's because user type multiple number in 1 time and so fast. So it's called keyup twice or more

Comment: The `keyup` event will be triggered for every key released. Even if multiple numbers are pressed, it will trigger the number of times it was pressed and it's the expected behavior. You could try focusing the next input field when the user types continuously and perform an action when the length of the OTP is reached to avoid any side effects. Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I initialized my event handling twice because I did it inside

```
document.onreadystatechange = function() {...}
```

But this function is being called multiple times depending on the phase:

`https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/readyState`

So I should've distinguished between events by reading value from document.readyState

Answer (score 0):

I put delay (500ms) on keyup but seems it's working.
But i don't know, is it correct way to avoid my issue?

Answer (score 0):

`.bind()` is deprecated. Try using `.on()` instead and see if that helps?

See https://api.jquery.com/bind/ for more info

*Edit:* same for `.unbind()`, use `.off()` instead. It may not help the problem but hopefully that's why.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Tried it but not solve the problem